# ModuleNotFoundError For Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I wrote a tool with an interface with PyQt5+Python3.6, and I want to pack into an .exe file to run on a machine without a Python environment. According to the online use of pyinstaller to pack, after the end of the package in the dist folder exe file is opened after the error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy._lib.messagestream'

This issue was revised after the hiddenimports of the .spec file was resolved:

```
hiddenimports=['scipy._lib.messagestream']
```

and then the new .exe file generated by the command:

```
pyinstaller x.spec
```

still reports an error.

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'typedefs'

Then, continue to add ... continue to error, all this error...

How do you solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 10):

Are you working in a virtual environment (venv)?
If so, you should add the site-packages path:

```
pyinstaller --paths path\to\venv\Lib\site-packages script.py
```

It happens to me with selenium module until I run pyinstaller with the --paths